# Individual axes labels in facet_wrap without scales="free"

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = as.factor(c(rep(2015, 3), rep(2016, 3), rep(2017,3))),
                 Tax = as.factor(c(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3))),
                 Depth = as.factor(c(10, 30, 50, 20,30,50,10,30,40)),
                 values= c(0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2))
```

I want to plot it with gaps for missing data and individual axis labels.

```
library(ggplot2)
```

The `scale` argument of `facet_wrap` gives individual axes, but is not performing as desired, as missing data is not reflected.:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Depth, values, fill=Tax)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(~Year, scale="free") +
  coord_flip()
```

Without `scales`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Depth, values, fill=Tax)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(~Year) +
  coord_flip()
```

The missing data is represented (which i want!), but it lacks axis labels (which i need).

is there anything i can do?

Comment: maybe not exactly what you need but you could add `ncol = 1` to the `facet_wrap` call which will put every panel in a new row and thus forcing the redrawing of the labels. but then you're stuck to this specific layout.

Comment: also you may want to look into this function from the lemon package: https://rdrr.io/cran/lemon/man/facet_rep.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this can be done using the `lemon` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lemon)

df <- data.frame(Year = as.factor(c(rep(2015, 3), rep(2016, 3), rep(2017,3))),
                 Tax = as.factor(c(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3))),
                 Depth = as.factor(c(10, 30, 50, 20,30,50,10,30,40)),
                 values= c(0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2))

ggplot(df, aes(Depth, values, fill=Tax)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+
   facet_rep_wrap(~Year,repeat.tick.labels = T) +
   coord_flip()
```